# Collect all Gerrit reviews

Tags: git, gerrit

For my current research, I want to gather all closed reviews from [Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com) instance, e.g from [Gerrit itself](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit).

My first attempt was to go via the REST API. However, there is a [limit for queries](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#capability_queryLimit), set by the Gerrit administrator. So I cannot collect all reviews and it is quite slow for large instances.

There would be a tool, namely [Perceval](https://github.com/chaoss/grimoirelab-perceval), but this requires SSH access, which I do not have, obviously.

So I think I need to go over git. As far as I understood, all reviews/changes under review are stored in `refs/changes/...`.

So I

```
git ls-remote https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit | grep /changes/ | awk '{print $2;}'
```

which lists all heads:

```
...
refs/changes/99/99999/3
refs/changes/99/99999/4
refs/changes/99/99999/5
refs/changes/99/99999/meta
...
```

Then I can iterate through this list. 
But

```
git fetch https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit refs/changes/99/99999/meta
```

does not work.

I also tried to mirror the git repository with

```
git clone --mirror https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit
```

but this does not include the `changes` folder.

Am I on the wrong track? What can I do instead? Of course, completely new ideas are also welcome!

Comment: What does the log say to make you think it does not work?

Comment: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: `git fetch` needs a git directory to store the fetched meta data. So just run `git init foo && cd foo` first.

Comment: But I am completely unsure, if I am on the right track at all. Maybe, the information from Gerrit stored in git are not suitable.

Comment: I tried to use `git clone --mirror` for including the `changes` folder, which does not work either.

Comment: I updated the question to be more precise. Thanks for your remarks so far!

Comment: In the repository created by `git clone --mirror`, you can find a file `packed-refs`. Open it and you can see all the refs.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, @E

Comment: The "git fetch" command worked pretty good to me. Did you got the "fatal: Not a git repository" just after the "git fetch" command?

Comment: Besides, `git show-ref` prints all the refs, which is better than reading `packed-refs`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, my approach is not possible - yet. As the [documentation states](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.15.1/dev-design.html#_infrastructure):

> Although an effort is underway to eliminate the use of the database
>   altogether, and to store all the metadata directly in the git
>   repositories themselves. So far, as of Gerrit 2.2.1, of all Gerrit’s
>   metadata, only the project configuration metadata has been migrated
>   out of the database and into the git repositories for each project.

So I hope there will be a solution in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
git fetch origin +refs/changes/*:refs/remotes/origin/changes/*
```

I haven't tried it for public Google Gerrit instance but it works for private Gerrit instance used in our company.

Maybe somebody find it useful.